# How to covert np.ndarray into astropy.coordinates.Angle class?

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

What is the quickest/most efficient way to convert a np.ndarray (importing numpy as np) into the astropy.coordinates.Angle class? I am having trouble keeping it as np.ndarray because the .wrap_at() operation will not work.

Comment: Are you using `astropy` functions and methods, or numpy ones?  Which ones?

Comment: I am using a numpy array and attempting to use an astropy function (.wrap_at()) with it, but it is required for me to convert to an astropy class (astropy.coordinates.Angle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly is your intention? `np.asarray` is quite ambiguous. If you are dealing with `np.ndarray` it is quite easy:

```
from astropy.coordinates import Angle
import astropy.units as u
import numpy as np

angles = np.array([100,200,300,400])
angles_quantity = a * u.degree # Could also be u.radian, u.arcmin, etc.
Angle(angles_quantity).wrap_at('360d')
```

But I'm not really sure if that solves your problem.

Converting such an `Angle` object back to a simple `np.ndarray` can be done with the `.value` attribute:

```
Angle(angles_quantity).wrap_at('360d').value # This returns a simple ndarray again.
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. I was confusing the function to initiate numpy arrays with the type itself. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, `np.array` != `np.ndarray`, quite emphatically. It's still a careless mistake I make to this day.