# Filling NumPy array with object instances?

Tags: python, object, numpy, sequence, astropy

I am trying to add object instances of `astropy` `Angles` to a `NumPy` array , and am getting an error:

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

the `Angle` objects look something like this:

`<Angle 1.2557346257567 deg>`

If I put them in a normal Python list, then I get:

```
s = [<Angle 1.2562500714928306 deg>,
     <Angle 1.2562500714928306 deg>,
     <Angle 1.2562500714928306 deg>]
len(s)
>>> 3
len(s[0])
>>> TypeError: 'Angle' object with a scalar value has no len()
```

So, my first question is, in what way is a Python object a sequence? And, since numpy arrays need to be initialized to specific dimensions, how do I find the "length" of this object so that I can load them into a numpy array?

Comment: Can you add some `Angle` documentation?  There are a lot of `numpy` users who don't know anything about `astropy`.

Comment: @hpaulj It's largely irrelevant, this is a generic problem that would occur when trying to put any object into a preallocated numpy array full of zeros. I just added `dtype = object` to my `numpy.zeros()` call and everything is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `astrop` package and don't know the details of the `Angle` object.  But I can make some Python and numpy observations.

`<Angle 1.2557346257567 deg>` is the string representation of this object, produced by its `__repr__` method.

The TypeError for `len(s[0])` means that this object does not a `__len__` method.  It is not a subclass of list, nor a specialized `numpy` array. Check its docs.  It may have a way of yielding a numeric value or values.

You don't say how you are trying to 'add' an Angle to an array, or what kind of array.  If the array is numeric, e.g. `dtype=float`, then doing

```
A[0]= <Angle...>
```

is not going to work, because `Angle` is not a number, nor does it produce one - at least not without some method.  You need to tell us what this target array is supposed to contain.  Numbers, angle objects?

You can build an array that contains objects.  `np.array(s)` might work.  It does when the list contains dictionary objects.

```
In [67]: ll
Out[67]: [{1: 2}, {}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]

In [68]: np.array(ll)
Out[68]: array([{1: 2}, {}, {'b': 2, 'a': 1}], dtype=object)
```

But `np.array([...])` can be tricky to use, since it's designed to produce a multidimensional array of numbers - if possible.

Or you might have to make `A = np.zeros((3,),dtype=object)` array, and assign values individually, `A[0]=s[0]`.  But such an object array is just a variant on a list.  It's not a 2d array of numbers.

From a previous `astropy` question:

[How to covert np.ndarray into astropy.coordinates.Angle class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094743/how-to-covert-np-ndarray-into-astropy-coordinates-angle-class)

```
Angle(angles_quantity).wrap_at('360d').value # This returns a simple ndarray again.
```

=================

Digging into the docs and astropy github code, I see that `Angle` is a subclass of `Quantity` which is a subclass of `ndarray`.  It tries, in effect to be an array (or scalar) with appropriate `unit` definition.

The `.value` method returns `self.view(np.ndarray)`, unless it's shape is 0d, in which case it returns `self.item()`, the scalar value.

So you should be able to define an `Angle` with multiple values, e.g.

```
Angle([1.23, 1.24, 1.25])
```

I don't know if you can join multiple `Angles` into one

```
Angle(s)
```

where `s` is your list of Angle objects, might work.  I don't see `Angle` versions of `concatenate` or `stack`.

Comment: Thank you, all I had to do was add `dtype = object` to my `numpy.zeros()` call, and it's working. I did know about the `.value` attribute on `Angle` objects, but I wanted to retain the `unit` information, and keeping them in their object form also keeps some nice `astropy` functionality.

Comment: I found that `Angle` is a subclass of `ndarray`.  See my edits for more on that.

Answer (score 4):

Don't create a list or array of `Angle` objects.
Instead, view `Angle` (and similar astropy classes) as a container object that adds a unit, and initialize it with a list or array.

For example:

```
>>> from astropy.coordinates import Angle
>>> from astropy import units
>>> angles = Angle([0, 30, 60, 90], unit=units.degree)
>>> angles
<Angle [  0., 30., 60., 90.] deg>
```

or

```
>>> angles = Angle(np.linspace(0, 90, 15, endpoint=True), unit=units.degree)
>>> angles
<Angle [  0.        ,  6.42857143, 12.85714286, 19.28571429, 25.71428571,
         32.14285714, 38.57142857, 45.        , 51.42857143, 57.85714286,
         64.28571429, 70.71428571, 77.14285714, 83.57142857, 90.        ] deg>
>>> len(angles)
15
```

This is a much more effective way of working with astropy classes: you can now simply multiply `angles` by a value, or perform other operations on it, just like for a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `dtype` of the array to `object`, a trivial example being

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.coordinates import Angle
a, b, c = Angle('1.2562500714928306d'), Angle('1.2562500714928306d'), Angle('1.2562500714928306d')
s = np.array([a, b, c], dtype=object)
```